# IIS Reverse Proxy to rewrite to internal Authentication Module (Keycloak)

Tags: iis, proxy, keycloak, reverse, arr

maybe someone can help me out.

I have a publicly accessible IIS Web Server (DMZ) with ARR enabled and use that IIS as a reverse proxy to rewrite all requests to an internal Website (QlikSense). So far so good. I sucessfully implemented keycloak as my Authentication module which is currently also installed on that external accessible DMZ server. Here comes my issue. Whenever I request the external URL, it sucessfully redirects me to my internal application (url rewrite) , and from there (over a redirect Uri) back to the keaycloak instance (which sits on the DMZ server) for authentication. Everything works fine but from an architectual point that setup is questoinable in my eyes. I would like the authentication to be happening internally and not on my DMZ server (behind the Reverse Proxy). But all my attempts to make keycloak authenticate on an internal installation   failed so far (page cannot be opend because server not found). What do I miss to make external requests being rewritten to the internal keycloak server without getting the error that SAFARI CANNOT OPEN THE PAGE BECAUSE THE SERVER CANNOT BE FOUND ?

I would like to have the authentication part being handeld internally (behind reverse Proxy) and not externally, since port 8080 needs to be open on the DMZ which is a security issue...
thanks

Comment: "I would like the authentication to be happening internally" is impossible. Your external users cannot access your internal network to provide user credentials (the cause behind server not found). If you do want to host keycloak internally, you probably need separate reverse proxy rules for keycloak URLs.

Comment: Thanks Lex, thanks for your thoughts. Going to dig into that topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.